# Get the element triggering an onclick event in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form where i've replaced the submit button with an input (with type=button) with an onclick which calls an existing function:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/admin/message_campaigns" class="new_message_campaign" id="new_message_campaign" method="post">
  <!-- some fields -->
      <input onclick="confirmSubmit();" type="button" value="Send" />
</form>
```

In the confirmSubmit, i'd like to be able to dynamically get the form object (to submit it), instead of having to hardcode the form's id, or pass it as part of the call to confirmSubmit().  I'd have thought that i could do this by first getting the dom element that was clicked on, ie something like this:

```
var form = $(this).parents("form");
```

where $(this) is the object that called the function, ie the input with the onclick.  This doesn't work though.  I think it *would* work if i'd set it up with the `.click(function(){` syntax.  Can i get the element that called the function in a different way?

EDIT - got the answer from @claudio below, for clarity here's the complete function and call:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/admin/message_campaigns" class="new_message_campaign" id="new_message_campaign" method="post">
  <!-- some fields -->
      <input onclick="confirmSubmit($(this));" type="button" value="Send" />
</form>
```

and the function itself.  Note that 'jConfirm' is a method of the jquery-alerts plugin (http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs/) but that's not really relevant to this question - the key thing was just to get the form object, not what's subsequently done with it:

```
function confirmSubmit(caller) {
  var form = caller.parents("form");
  jConfirm('Are you sure?', 'Please Confirm', function(result){
    if (result) {
      form.submit();
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can pass the inline handler the `this` keyword, obtaining the element which fired the event.

like,

```
onclick="confirmSubmit(this);"
```

Comment: Thanks claudio - how would i handle that in the function?  I've tried this `function confirmSubmit(caller) {
  var form = caller.parents("form");` but it didn't work...

Comment: caller is a DOM element, so you'd need to do confirmSubmit($(this)) for .parents('form') to work.

Comment: got it: just needed to "jqueryfy" caller:  `confirmSubmit(caller) { var form = $(caller).parents("form");`

Comment: ah right - same thing but at the other end :) I'll do it your way.  Thanks!

Comment: I was dynamically loading tables from python via flask and had to use `onclick="my_function($(this))"` as opposed to just using `(this)`.  Hope that helps anyone having trouble with this.

Answer (score 50):

If you don't want to pass the clicked on element to the function through a parameter, then you need to access the event object that is happening, and get the target from that object. This is most easily done if you bind the click event like this:

```
$('#sendButton').click(function(e){
    var SendButton = $(e.target);
    var TheForm = SendButton.parents('form');
    TheForm.submit();

    return false;
});
```

Comment: thanks @laurencek, i know that i can do it like that if i set it with a jquery "click" call, i was wondering about the onclick case.  Cheers tho.

Comment: You can do it by setting the onclick in the same way: document.getElementById('...').onclick = function(e){ target = e.target; }, Of course for IE its a little different, target = window.event.target

Answer (score 26):

Try this

```
<input onclick="confirmSubmit(event);" type="button" value="Send" />
```

Along with this

```
function confirmSubmit(event){
            var domElement =$(event.target);
            console.log(domElement.attr('type'));
        }
```

I tried it in firefox, it prints the 'type' attribute of dom Element clicked. I guess you can then get the form via the parents() methods using this object.

Comment: To get the form: $(event.target).parents('form')

Answer (score 12):

It's top google stackoverflow question, but all answers are not jQuery related!

```
$(".someclass").click(
    function(event)
    {
        console.log(event, this);
    }
);
```

'event' contains 2 important values:

**event.currentTarget** - element to which event is triggered ('.someclass' element)

**event.target** - element clicked (in case when inside '.someclass' [div] are other elements and you clicked on of them)

**this** - is set to triggered element ('.someclass'), but it's JavaScript element, not jQuery element, so if you want to use some jQuery function on it, you must first change it to jQuery element: **$(this)**

When your refresh the page and reload the scripts again; this method not work. You have to use jquery "unbind" method.

Answer (score 0):

## First Way: Send trigger element using `this`

```
<button id="btn01" onClick="myFun(this)">B1</button>
<button id="btn02" onClick="myFun(this)">B2</button>
<button id="btn03" onClick="myFun(this)">B3</button>

<script>
  function myFun(trigger_element)
  {
      // Get your element:
      var clicked_element = trigger_element

      alert(clicked_element.id + "Was clicked!!!");
  }
</script>
```

> This way send an object of type: `HTMLElement` and you get the element itself. you don't need to care if the element has an id or any other property. And it works by itself just fine.

---

## Second Way: Send trigger element id using `this.id`

```
<button id="btn01" onClick="myFun(this.id)">B1</button>
<button id="btn02" onClick="myFun(this.id)">B2</button>
<button id="btn03" onClick="myFun(this.id)">B3</button>

<script>
  function myFun(clicked_id)
  {
      // Get your element:
      var clicked_element = document.getElementById(clicked_id)

      alert(clicked_id + "Was clicked!!!");
  }
</script>
```

> This way send an object of type: `String` and you DO NOT get the element itself. So before use, you need to make sure that your element already has an id.
>
> You mustn't send the element id by yourself such as `onClick="myFun(btn02)"`. it's not CLEAN CODE and it makes your code lose functionality.