# how to find target is button in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

In document click event how to return if target is button element

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    if(e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'button')
```

Whether above code was correct ?

Comment: Well that tests that it is _not_ a button, but you've got the general idea right. Unless you think it doesn't use enough jQuery methods?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071095/get-the-element-triggering-an-onclick-event-in-jquery ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You may do only

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
  if ( $( e.currentTarget ).is( ":button" ) ) {
    // Do things
  }
});
```

**Why would you use `:button` instead of `button`?**

Because that way you can detect if it's a `<input type="button">` OR a `<button>` tag, aswell the other input types which render as buttons.
If you're unsure about using this selector, check the [:button selector](http://api.jquery.com/button-selector/) jQuery docs.

Comment: `this` will never be a button in this example.

Comment: Damn, forgot about that. Fixed.

Comment: Big plus for adding the :button selector. Did not know about that

Comment: @gustavohenke : it was not working i'm using button from server side control

Answer (score 6):

Faster :

```
$(this).is('button');
```

Comment: Actually raw JS should be faster. Your solution is shorter :)

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa true :) jQuery is always faster to write :) I meant it that way. And I was lazy :P

Answer (score 4):

You can use .is() to test the given element against a selecor.

Also you can use [:button](http://api.jquery.com/button-selector/) selector to test, if you want only element button then you can use `is('button')` element selector

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
  if ($( e.target ).is(":button")) {
    //check
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    if($(this).is('button')){
           //your codes..
    }

});
```

Comment: this refers to document here. And what about input type button? Even we don't know what OP calls a 'button'.

Answer (score 1):

**Pure JS FTW!**

```
e.target.nodeName === 'BUTTON'
```

or if you have **array** of dom elements

```
if(['BUTTON', 'INPUT'].indexOf(e.target.nodeName) !== -1){
  // clicked on button/input
}
```

It's not mistake. Capital letters for HTML.

> In XHTML (or any other XML format), text_field's value would read
>   "div". However, in HTML, text_field's value would read "DIV", because
>   nodeName and tagName return in upper case on HTML elements in DOMs
>   flagged as HTML documents.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeName

Answer (score 0):

jquery handles this perfectly: `$(this).is(nameOfTargetElement);`