# $(this) confusion within click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason I have to use pure js with jquery. I have tags like this

```
<a onclick="openClose()">Click</a>
<div class="spoilermain">content</div>
```

and this is my js

```
    function openClose(){
        $('.spoilertop').next('.spoilermain').toggle();
    }
```

The problem is if there is more than one spoilertop then all will be toggled. How to use $(this) in this case? I know I can select the a then use $(this) but for some reason I must fired the openClose().

Comment: `spoilertop` what is it? the parent wrapper...

Comment: Try to pass `this` as argument. `<a onclick="openClose(this)">Click</a>`

Comment: You find your answer here: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071095/get-the-element-triggering-an-onclick-event-in-jquery)

Comment: Why can you not attach your events with jQuery?

Comment: your question is not understandable..

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the onclick event, add an open-close class

```
<a class=".open-close">Click</a>
```

then just call in your script:

```
$('.open-close').click(function(){
        $(this).next('.spoilermain').toggle(); 
});
```

Comment: This is actually the prettiest solution.

Answer (score 2):

pass this as a parameter at the time of function calling

html code

```
<a onclick="openClose(this)">Click</a>
<div class="spoilermain">content</div>
```

javascript code

```
function openClose(ele){
        $(ele).next('.spoilermain').toggle();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this? pass "this" as an argument to onclick function handler in your html and than you can use it in the function later

```
<a onclick="openClose(this)">Click</a>
    <div class="spoilermain">content</div>
```

js

```
function openClose(obj){
    $(obj).next('.spoilermain').toggle();
  // this is available here
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
function openClose(obj){
    $(obj).next('.spoilermain').toggle();
  // this is available here
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a onclick="openClose(this)">Click</a>
    <div class="spoilermain">content</div>
```

Comment: Your function would throw a js error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token this`

Comment: @MichalPaszkiewicz updated and working now can you please take your donwvote back, point was to pass "this" in argument