# How to have a text box for each individual image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I change this so that each text box only displays the text for each image individually? I'm really new to all this and I'm finding it very difficult to do what I want.

```js
function showText(text) {
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = text;
  document.getElementById("text2").innerHTML = text;
}

function hide() {
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("text2").innerHTML = "";
}
```

```html
<LINK REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" HREF="test2css.css">
<h1> ufo test page </h1>

<img src="ufo.png" id="image" onMouseOver="showText('its a ufo baby')" onMouseOut="hide();">
<div id="text" style="position:absolute; left: 100px; top: 200px;"> </div>

<br>

<img src="alien.png" id="image2" onMouseOver="showText('its a grey baby')" onMouseOut="hide();">
<div id="text2" style="position:absolute; left: 150px; top: 400px;"> </div>
```

Comment: Does it have to be in JavaScript? You should be able to create the same effect with HTML and CSS alone.

Comment: could you be more specific as to what you want to do

Comment: Pass the element to your `showText` function. Follow the pattern described here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6071095/215552

Comment: yes, it has to be javascript as it is part of a module at uni. I need to show that I've used it in the site somewhere. sorry for being so vague, next time ill be a lot more specific. thanks anyways, every input has been appreciated as ive been trying to figure this out all day. D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the way you've approached this, you'll need two functions for each text div so they can be shown and hidden individually.

```js
function showText(text){
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML=text;
}
function hideText(){
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML="";
}

function showText2(text){
document.getElementById("text2").innerHTML=text;
}
function hideText2(){
document.getElementById("text2").innerHTML="";
}
```

```html
<LINK REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" HREF="test2css.css">
<h1> ufo test page </h1>

<img src="ufo.png" id="image" onMouseOver="showText('its a ufo baby')" onMouseOut="hideText();">
<div id="text" style= "position:absolute; left: 100px; top: 200px;"> </div>

<br>

<img src="alien.png" id="image2" onMouseOver="showText2('its a grey baby')"     onMouseOut="hideText2();">
<div id="text2" style= "position:absolute; left: 150px; top: 400px;"> </div>
```

This is a simple fix to your code. If you have lots of images, you might want to look at other ways of doing this.

Comment: this appears to be a perfect solution for me as I have to run javascript in the page somewhere to get credited for using it. its a simple website module I am doing as part of my masters in GIS. there will never be more than 3 pictures per page so I give this answer a BIG thumbs up!! thanks everyone who contributed and i'll remember to be a lot more specific if I'm ever asking again, you guys are great!! D