# Javascript: Adding and removing elements to dom

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to dynamically add new elements to my html. But i am currently stuck on the "second level". It starts with a single div where new elements will get stored at:

```
<div id="inputquestions"></div>
```

When I click a button, new elements will get added to the div via a javascript function which looks something like this

```
function addQuestion() {
        var div = document.createElement('div');

        questionID++; // increment questionID to get a unique ID for the new element

        div.className = 'newQuestion';

        div.id = 'newQuestionID';

        div.innerHTML =
            "<div class='input-group'>" +
            "<input id='question-" + questionID + "' class='form-control' name='questionbox' type='text' placeholder='New Question'/>" +
            "<button class='btn btn-secondary' onclick='removeQuestion(this.parentNode)' type='button'>Remove</button>" +
            "</div>" +
            "<div class='btn-group' role='group' aria-label='Basic example'>" +
            "<button class='btn btn-secondary' onclick='addRadioButton()' type='button'>+ Radiobutton</button>" +             
            "</div>";

        document.getElementById('inputquestions').appendChild(div);
    }
```

This will create multiple divs inside the first div and I now want each div to create new divs for them individually but can't figure out how to do it. How does my function `addRadioButton()` have to look like in order to make the new divs appear inside the div I pressed the button at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function `addRadioButton()` you can look at `event.target.parentElement` to get the `<div>` that contains the `<button>` that was clicked on.

Then you add the new elements into that `<div>`.

Comment: Could you please specify your answer or provide a short code-snippet?

Comment: What @intervalia left out is that you can assume the addRadioButton will have a 'this' that you can pass as parameter into your click handler function:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071095/get-the-element-triggering-an-onclick-event-in-jquery

And once you have the element that triggered the click you can access the parent elements using it.

Comment: I didn't leave it out. I find `event.target` to be more reliable in all cases.